# OpenNewTab stopped working on IE after unknown Windows update

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I use HP UFT v14 and windows 7 64 bit OS. After some unknown windows patch my "OpenNewTab" does not open a new tab anymore. I suspect windows update has reset some IE settings, but I'm not 100% sure. Any help is appreciated

P.S. - It was a working code before windows update and OpenNewTab could open new tab successfully then

Code snippet:

```
SystemUtil.Run "iexplore.exe" , "https://www.google.com"
With Browser("XYZ")
    With .Page("XYZ")
        .WebEdit("username").Set uac_username
        .WebEdit("password").SetSecure uac_pass
        .WebButton("Sign In").Click
    End With
    .OpenNewTab 'This line executes without error but no action seen on IE
End With

'Open portal URL in second tab of IE
With Browser("CreationTime:=1")
    .Sync
    .Navigate "https://www.facebook.com"
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround thanks to [solution](http://www.advancedqtp.com/old_forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=6164) from Asiq Ahmed

Use below line of code instead of OpenNewTab:

```
Browser("XYZ").Object.Navigate portal_url,Clng(&H800)
```